# What is the meaning or purpose of inertial motions

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, lorentz-symmetry

It seems to me that, except for light, inertial motion is never possible in real world where there is gravity everywhere. It is at best some kind of idealization.

But why inertial motions are so prominent as part of Special Relativity and the Lorentz transformations etc?

It seems that the whole notion of Lorentz transformation hinges on having inertial frame while in reality there can be no such thing as inertial frame given the presence of gravity.

Comment: Inertial motion is motion without an external force. Gravity is not a force, hence it doesn't cause problems with the definition. What does cause problems for many observers is the false belief that the surface of earth is an inertial system.

Comment: @CuriousOne What do you mean "gravity is not a force"?  Within the special relativity arena, it provides an acceleration to an object, and is thus a force.  How does it differ from the electrostatic force?

Comment: @garyp - Within the context of special relativity, gravity doesn't exist. Special relativity can accommodate electromagnetism, quantum mechanics, the weak interaction, and the strong interaction. But it cannot accommodate gravitation. For that, you need general relativity (and that cannot accommodate quantum mechanics).

Comment: @garyp: Within the context of Newtonian mechanics gravity is an acceleration and that acceleration is zero in the inertial frame of any test mass. What's not zero are the acceleration and forces test masses are subjected to in non-inertial frames like the laboratory bench frame. But then, if you look at the definition of inertial frame, the lab bench wasn't mentioned there. Moreover, if you are an American resident, then the government that you are paying taxes to has spent well over \$100 billion on providing a much better approximation to an inertial frame. It's called the ISS.

Comment: If we can just forget our theories of Special or General relativity, can we agree that in reality, there can be no inertial frame given that gravity is everywhere?

Comment: @southwind: Nope, you got it 100% wrong.

Comment: @CuriousOne, what did I say was wrong? Just because SR does not deal with gravity does not mean the apple won't fall, right?

Comment: @southwind: You have the definition of inertial motion/inertial system wrong. The existence of inertial systems (in which physics looks "simple") is a matter of fact, not a matter of how we describe (or fail to describe) them in any particular theory. Neither Newtonian mechanics nor special relativity have the mathematical tools to describe the situation of inertial systems in a situation with gravity well, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: @CuriousOne, No, I am saying inertial frame does not exist in reality. And I am saying reality trumps whatever the theory or semantics you can come up with. BTW, this is not an easy question, so just be careful of what you say.

Comment: @southwind, at this point I am saying that I have no reason to argue with a person who has a closed mind. You are right, this is not an easy question and you have failed to understand it, so far. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

For any isolated object, i.e. one that is having an external force applied to it, the frame that object lives in is locally inertial. By locally I mean that if you consider a small enough region of spacetime around the object it will be impossible to tell the frame isn't inertial. How small this volume is depends on how curved spacetime is. This is an exceedingly important principle in general relativity or indeed in anything that uses [differentiable manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold).

Another way of putting this is that even in general relativity, if you consider a small enough region the physics can be described to arbitrary accuracy by special relativity.

So while you are correct that there is no such thing as an inertial frame (unless you're lucky enough to be doing physics in a universe free of matter) the concept is a very useful one. In many cases frames are close enough to inertial that we can ignore the deviations. After all, quantum field theory uses only special relativity but it can make [the most accurate predictions ever made by a scientific theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_tests_of_QED).

**Response to comment:**

I'm not sure what you mean by *The motion of inertial frame is observable*. An inertial frame is not an object, it's a choice of coordinates. Motion relative to an inertial frame is observable.

We know our frame is inertial if all the objects moving relative to it obey Newton's first law. That is, if we set something moving and apply no force to it then it will continue moving in a straight line at a constant speed.

Let's consider a specific example. Suppose I'm floating around in the ISS, and I place a ball at rest relative to me but a metre nearer the Earth than I am. The ball will just stay there, so I could be forgiven for thinking that the coordinate system I'm using to locate points inside the ISS constitutes an inertial frame. And for all practical purposes it does.

The trouble is that the ball is actually in a slightly (one metre) lower orbit than I am and its orbital period is therefore shorter. If I watch the ball for a long time I'll see it begin to move relative to me i.e. it isn't obeying Newton's first law and I can tell my frame isn't inertial. But the period of the ball differs from mine by only about 1 part in 20 million so I'd need to watch for a long, long time.

So the point is that to within a very small error the coordinates I've set up inside the ISS do constitute an inertial frame within a radius of a metre from the origin. But suppose I was doing some very sensitive experiment where that 1 in 20 million deviation was significant. Well I could make the experiment one millimetre in size instead of one metre, and that would reduce the error to less than one part in a billion.

And so on. I can make my frame approximately inertial to whatever accuracy I want by reducing the size over which I use it.

Comment: I like this explanation. While we are on this I have another question. The motion of inertial frame is observable in the sense of Einstien's scheme, but what exactly are we observing if inertial frames are of tiny scale. Does this mean that inertial motions are extensive?

Comment: @southwind: I've edited my answer to respond to your comment

Comment: I meant inertial motion of a massive object. I was thinking since inertial motions really happens in small scale but somehow in reality they seem possible, so maybe those small scale inertial motions are addictive. Now you mentioned Newton's 1st law, have you thought of Newton's 3rd law? I have trouble seeing how a reaction force comes about. I know it is true, but there seems no theory that explains the mechanism of this automatic reactionary force.

Comment: @southwind: Newton's third law is just conservation of momentum, and it's hard to see the connection with your original question.